# Dynamically Cover Image with Rectangle in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React App where I am showing live updates on NFL games. I am trying to take an image of a football field and dynamically cover it with a rect SVG element based on how many yards the team has gone, and what isn't covered is how many yards the team has left to go. What I have looks like the below.

[image]

I can dynamically change the size of the rectangle, but if the screen is ever resized, the rectangle moves to another location and no longer covers the image.

How can I accomplish this so that the shading always covers whatever percentage of the image I'd like no matter how the screen is resized? My current strategy is a super unsophisticated approach given that I am new to using CSS:

```
<img className = "col l5 offset-l2" src = {"./field.jpg"} alt = {this.props.team1} style = {{height:"40%",width:"40%"}}></img>
<svg width="600" height="205" style = {{"margin-left":"635px","margin-top":"-110%","margin-bottom":"1.5%"}}>
        <rect width="206" height="210" style={{"z-index":"9",position:"absolute","fill":"rgb(0,0,255)","opacity":"0.4","stroke-width":"0","stroke":"rgb(0,0,0)"}} />
</svg>
```

Comment: You need to position the SVG in terms of %s (from top and left of the img). If you find yourself using fixed units like px then it won't be responsive. If you put up a working snipped (remember to include react) then I'll have a better chance of helping.

Comment: Make the `img` as a background of a div. The position the `svg` in it absolutely. You can resize the `svg` as you like.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. How do I start by putting the SVG in terms of percentage from the top of the image? I understand how to move it upwards using %, but I don't know how to anchor it at the top of the image. Once I know that I will share a working example. Thank you again!

Comment: @Azu That did it- thank you for the quick reply and for helping me solve this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    background-image: url("./field.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: cover; /*if doesn't work, try 'contain'*/
    position: relative;
}

.container svg{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <svg width="600" height="205">
       <rect width="206" height="210" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You rock, thank you!!